# Ceph dashboard cannot connect to RGW while SSL is enabled

Tags: storage, ceph

I have deployed ceph cluster using Cephadm , all things are working fine until I've enabled the ssl in the rgw service with a proper ssl certificate - that matches the hostname of the RGW node (I have 3 nodes) and rgw daemon is running on one node - I can't access the object gateway or any tabs under unless I've disabled SSL, however the api url opens normally the issue is within the dashboard.

Ceph version is: 18.2

Logs:

[b'{"status": "500 Internal Server Error", "detail": "The server encountered an unexpected condition which prevented it from fulfilling the request.", "request_id": "8ad544cc-83fc-4d51-828f-3041151388d1", "traceback": "Traceback (most recent call last):\n File \"/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cherrypy/_cprequest.py\", line 638, in respond\n self._do_respond(path_info)\n File \"/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cherrypy/_cprequest.py\", line 697, in _do_respond\n response.body = self.handler()\n File \"/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cherrypy/lib/encoding.py\", line 219, in **call**\n self.body = self.oldhandler(*args, **kwargs)\n File \"/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cherrypy/_cptools.py\", line 230, in wrap\n return self.newhandler(innerfunc, *args, **kwargs)\n File \"/usr/share/ceph/mgr/dashboard/services/exception.py\", line 58, in dashboard_exception_handler\n raise error\n File \"/usr/share/ceph/mgr/dashboard/services/exception.py\", line 47, in dashboard_exception_handler\n return handler(*args, **kwargs)\n File \"/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cherrypy/_cpdispatch.py\", line 54, in **call**\n return self.callable(*self.args, **self.kwargs)\n File \"/usr/share/ceph/mgr/dashboard/controllers/_base_controller.py\", line 263, in inner\n ret = func(*args, **kwargs)\n File \"/usr/share/ceph/mgr/dashboard/controllers/_rest_controller.py\", line 191, in wrapper\n return func(*vpath, **params)\n File \"/usr/share/ceph/mgr/dashboard/controllers/rgw.py\", line 108, in list\n 'port': int(metadata['frontend_config#0'].split('port=')[1])\nValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '433 ssl_certificate=config://rgw/cert/rgw.rgw'\n", "version": "18.4.0"}']

- I tried another ssl certificate with another hostname
- Reinstalled the whole cluster

with no luck

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely this [bug](https://tracker.ceph.com/issues/63564), I see the same in my 18.2.0 test cluster. And it is already fixed in the main branch, I expect it to be in the 18.2.1 release, but I'm not sure though.